# Adding a new native module using CMake yields "Error: exception during working with external system:"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

There is a CMake example given by Google for the android-ndk built, in which a number of different modules are being loaded into the project via CMake. The project can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/cmake).

On trying to add a new module named `varnam` into this existing project,
I am getting the following error

`Error: exception during working with external system:`

The modified project can be found [here](https://github.com/malayaleecoder/libvarnam-Android/tree/master/CMake) and the log for the same can be found [here](https://github.com/malayaleecoder/libvarnam-Android/blob/master/CMake/log).

The Android Studio version used is `2.2 preview 5`. Help in any form would be great.